# PostgreSQL Getting error in order to change explicit type cast

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM WASADMIN.DAILYTXNSREPORT 
WHERE UBACCOUNTID = '01ED10EOD0100' 
  AND UBTXNAMT = '109.63' 
  AND UBTYPE = 'I' 
  AND UBVALUEDTTM LIKE '11/7/2015  12:00:00 AM%' 
  AND UBTXNAMTCR = '109.63' 
  AND UBTXNAMTDR = '0.0' 
  AND UBTXNCODE = 'IAP' 
  AND UBTXNNARRATION = 'Fixed Narrative:Interest Application' 
  AND UBTXNSRCBRANCH = '70000001.0' 
  AND UBTXNBASEEQ = '109.63' 
  AND UBCHANNELID = 'UXP'
```

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WASADMIN.UBTB_DAILYTXNSREPORT WHERE UBACCOUNTID='01ED10EOD0100' AND UBTXNAMT='109.63' AND UBTYPE='I' AND UBVALUEDTTM LIKE '11/7/2...
>
> ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Position: 139

Expected answer: to get the count

Comment: `UBVALUEDTTM` seems to be a `TIMESTAMP` - and does are **NOT** stored in a string format - so you **cannot** use the `LIKE` operator on this  .....

Comment: `select to_char('11/7/2015  12:00:00 AM'::timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:mi:ss AM') like '11/07/2015 12:00:00 AM%'; t`

Comment: LIKE is for string values, not for timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE is for comparing string values, not for timestamps.

I am not sure what the LIKE condition  is supposed to achieve, but it seem you want to find rows where `` is equal to midnight of `2015-11-07`. The following would do that:

```
AND ubvaluedttm = timestamp '2015-11-07 00:00:00'
```

A range condition is probably closer to what the LIKE condition would do:

```
AND ubvaluedttm >= timestamp '2015-11-07 00:00:00' 
AND ubvaluedttm <= timestamp '2015-11-07 00:00:00.999999'
```